# Database Class Creator

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net, .net-2.0

**Overview**

I've written a class that will create C# code. The output is a single .cs file for each table in the default database (the database is defined inside a web.config file). I'm looking for a code review on this class alone, *not* on the generated code. This `DatabaseClassCreator` class uses the `DatabaseAccess` class for some of its database access. The `DatabaseAccess` class can be seen [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2578/database-access-class) as I'm asking for a code review of that class as well. If you are not interested in seeing the `DatabaseAccess` class, there is one static method `ExecSQL`, which returns a single `DataTable` with the results of the passed SQL.

Two notes:

1. This was developed and is being used for a ASP.NET project, which is the reason for the `BulletedList`.
2. This class has to work in a C# .NET 2 environment, so anything that's more modern would be interesting to me, but please note in your answer if the comments/feedback require a newer .NET version.

```
/// <summary>
/// This class will create c# class files to access spesific
/// tables in a database.
/// </summary>
public static class DatabaseClassCreator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create class files for all the non-system tables in the current
    /// default database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="OutputPath">The output location for the class files. This
    /// is a fully qualified path.</param>
    public static void CreateAllTables(string OutputPath)
    {
        BulletedList bl = new BulletedList();
        CreateAllTables(bl, OutputPath);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Create class files for all the non-system tables in the current
    /// default database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="StatusBulletList">A BulletedList where status information can be
    /// added to.</param>
    /// <param name="OutputPath">The output location for the class files. This
    /// is a fully qualified path.</param>
    public static void CreateAllTables(BulletedList StatusBulletList, string OutputPath)
    {
        DataTable table = ListDatabaseTables();

        if (table == null)
        {
            ListItem liRowName = new ListItem();
            liRowName.Text = "Database Error";
            StatusBulletList.Items.Add(liRowName);
            return;
        }

        // Loop through the tables and create the accessor classes
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            if (row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() != "syssegments" && row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() != "sysconstraints")
            {
                ListItem liRowName = new ListItem();
                liRowName.Text = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                StatusBulletList.Items.Add(liRowName);
                CreateSingleTable(StatusBulletList, OutputPath, row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a DataTable containing all the table names in the default
    /// database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>DataTable listing the table names.</returns>
    public static DataTable ListDatabaseTables()
    {
        string SQL;
        DataTable table = null;

        // Grab all the table names from the current database
        SQL = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE NOT TABLE_NAME='sysdiagrams' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_TYPE= 'BASE TABLE'";
        table = DatabaseAccess.ExecSQL(SQL);

        return table;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Output a class file for the requested table in the current default database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="OutputPath">The output location for the class files. This
    /// is a fully qualified path.</param>
    /// <param name="TableName">The table name</param>
    public static void CreateSingleTable(string OutputPath, String TableName)
    {
        BulletedList bl = new BulletedList();
        CreateSingleTable(bl, OutputPath, TableName);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Output a class file for the requested table in the current default database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="OutputPath">The output location for the class files. This
    /// is a fully qualified path.</param>
    /// <param name="StatusBulletList">A BulletedList where status information can be
    /// added to.</param>
    /// <param name="TableName">The table name</param>
    public static void CreateSingleTable(BulletedList StatusBulletList, string OutputPath, String TableName)
    {
        string SQL;
        IDataReader reader = null;
        DataTable schema = null;
        List<TableFieldInfo> fields = new List<TableFieldInfo>();

        // Grab the current table
        SQL = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM " + TableName;
        reader = ExecSQLReader("", SQL);

        // Get the table schema
        if (reader != null)
            schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();

        // Grab the field information we need
        if (schema != null)
        {
            foreach (DataRow myField in schema.Rows)
            {
                TableFieldInfo f = new TableFieldInfo();
                f.name = myField["ColumnName"].ToString();
                f.type = myField["ProviderSpecificDataType"].ToString();
                f.allowNull = bool.Parse(myField["AllowDBNull"].ToString());
                f.readOnly = bool.Parse(myField["IsReadOnly"].ToString());
                f.maxSize = int.Parse(myField["ColumnSize"].ToString());
                fields.Add(f);

                string info = "---> " + f.name + " (" + f.type + ")";
                if (f.readOnly)
                    info += " (RO)";
                else
                    info += " (RW)";
                if (f.allowNull)
                    info += " (Null)";
                StatusBulletList.Items.Add(new ListItem(info));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ListItem liRowName = new ListItem();
            liRowName.Text = "Schema Error";
            StatusBulletList.Items.Add(liRowName);
        }

        // Clean the table name for the filesystem and c# names
        TableName = TableName.Replace('(', '_').Replace(')', '_').Replace('~', '_'); ;

        // Open the file
        string filename = OutputPath + "\\DBT_" + TableName + ".cs";
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename);

        // Add File Comments
        sw.WriteLine("// ");
        sw.WriteLine("// This file is auto generated based on the database");
        sw.WriteLine("// DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE, EVER");
        sw.WriteLine("// Inherit this class and make changes there");
        sw.WriteLine("// DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE, CHANGES WILL BE LOST");
        sw.WriteLine("// ");
        sw.WriteLine("");

        // Add Using statements
        sw.WriteLine("using System;");
        sw.WriteLine("using System.Collections.Generic;");
        sw.WriteLine("using System.Data;");
        sw.WriteLine("using System.Data.SqlClient;");
        sw.WriteLine("");

        // Open the class
        sw.WriteLine("public class DBT" + TableName + " : DatabaseAccess");
        sw.WriteLine("{");

        // Add accessors
        foreach (TableFieldInfo f in fields)
        {
            if (getType(f.type) == "int")
                sw.WriteLine("\tprivate " + getType(f.type) + " _" + f.name + " = -1;");
            else if (getType(f.type) == "float")
                sw.WriteLine("\tprivate " + getType(f.type) + " _" + f.name + " = -1;");
            else if (getType(f.type) == "DateTime")
                sw.WriteLine("\tprivate " + getType(f.type) + " _" + f.name + " = new DateTime(1753, 1, 1);");
            else if (getType(f.type) == "byte[]")
                sw.WriteLine("\tprivate " + getType(f.type) + " _" + f.name + " = new byte[1];");
            else
                sw.WriteLine("\tprivate " + getType(f.type) + " _" + f.name + ";");

            sw.WriteLine("\tpublic " + getType(f.type) + " " + f.name);
            sw.WriteLine("\t{");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\tget { return _" + f.name + "; }");
            string protect = "";
            if (f.readOnly)
                protect = "protected ";

            if (f.maxSize == 0 || getType(f.type) != "string")
                sw.WriteLine("\t\t" + protect + "set { _" + f.name + " = value; }");
            else
            {
                sw.WriteLine("\t\t" + protect + "set");
                sw.WriteLine("\t\t{");
                sw.WriteLine("\t\t\tif(value.Length <= " + f.maxSize.ToString() + ")");
                sw.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t_" + f.name + " = value;");
                sw.WriteLine("\t\t\telse");
                sw.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t_" + f.name + " = value.Substring(0, " + (f.maxSize).ToString() + ");");
                sw.WriteLine("\t\t}");
            }
            sw.WriteLine("\t}");
            sw.WriteLine("");
        }

        // Add the Constructors
        sw.WriteLine("\tprivate string _connectionString = \"\";");
        sw.WriteLine("\tpublic DBT" + TableName + "()");
        sw.WriteLine("\t{");
        sw.WriteLine("\t}");
        sw.WriteLine("");
        sw.WriteLine("\tpublic DBT" + TableName + "(string ConnectionString)");
        sw.WriteLine("\t{");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t_connectionString = ConnectionString;");
        sw.WriteLine("\t}");
        sw.WriteLine("");
        sw.WriteLine("\tpublic DBT" + TableName + "(int itemID)");
        sw.WriteLine("\t{");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\tthis.Select(itemID);");
        sw.WriteLine("\t}");
        sw.WriteLine("");
        sw.WriteLine("\tpublic DBT" + TableName + "(string ConnectionString, int itemID)");
        sw.WriteLine("\t{");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t_connectionString = ConnectionString;");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\tthis.Select(itemID);");
        sw.WriteLine("\t}");
        sw.WriteLine("");

        // Add the insert method
        StatusBulletList.Items.Add(new ListItem("<--- public void Insert()"));
        sw.WriteLine("\tpublic void Insert()");
        sw.WriteLine("\t{");
        foreach (TableFieldInfo f in fields)
        {
            if (f.readOnly == true)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("\t\tif(_" + f.name + " != -1)");
                sw.WriteLine("\t\t\treturn;");
                sw.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
        sw.Write("\t\tstring SQL = \"INSERT INTO " + TableName + " (");
        int count = fields.Count;
        foreach (TableFieldInfo f in fields)
        {
            count--;
            if (f.readOnly != true)
            {
                string fieldName = f.name;
                if (fieldName.ToUpper() == "DEFAULT")
                    fieldName = "[" + fieldName + "]";

                if (count != 0)
                    sw.Write(fieldName + ", ");
                else
                    sw.Write(fieldName);
            }
        }
        sw.Write(") VALUES (");
        count = fields.Count;
        foreach (TableFieldInfo f in fields)
        {
            count--;
            if (f.readOnly != true)
            {
                if (count != 0)
                    sw.Write("@" + f.name + ", ");
                else
                    sw.Write("@" + f.name);
            }
        }
        sw.WriteLine("); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ID;\";");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\tList<SqlParameter> parms = new List<SqlParameter>();");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\tDataTable table = null;");
        sw.WriteLine("");
        foreach (TableFieldInfo f in fields)
        {
            if (f.readOnly != true)
            {
                if (getType(f.type) == "DateTime")
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\tif(_" + f.name + " != new DateTime(1753, 1, 1))");
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\t\tparms.Add(new SqlParameter(\"@" + f.name + "\", _" + f.name + "));");
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\telse");
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\t\tparms.Add(new SqlParameter(\"@" + f.name + "\", null));");
                }
                else
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\tparms.Add(new SqlParameter(\"@" + f.name + "\", _" + f.name + "));");
                }
            }
        }
        sw.WriteLine("");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\tif (_connectionString == \"\")");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t{");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t\ttable = ExecSQL(SQL, parms);");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t}");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\telse");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t{");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t\ttable = ExecSQL(_connectionString, SQL, parms);");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t}");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\tif (table != null && table.Rows.Count == 1)");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t{");
        foreach (TableFieldInfo f in fields)
        {
            if (f.readOnly == true)
                sw.WriteLine("\t\t\t_" + f.name + " = int.Parse(table.Rows[0][\"ID\"].ToString());");
        }
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t}");
        sw.WriteLine("\t}");
        sw.WriteLine("");


        // Add the update method
        StatusBulletList.Items.Add(new ListItem("<--- public void Update()"));
        sw.WriteLine("\tpublic void Update()");
        sw.WriteLine("\t{");
        sw.Write("\t\tstring SQL = \"UPDATE " + TableName + " SET ");
        count = fields.Count;
        foreach (TableFieldInfo f in fields)
        {
            count--;
            if (f.readOnly != true)
            {
                string fieldName = f.name;
                if (fieldName.ToUpper() == "DEFAULT")
                    fieldName = "[" + fieldName + "]";

                if (count != 0)
                    sw.Write(fieldName + "=@" + f.name + ", ");
                else
                    sw.Write(fieldName + "=@" + f.name + " ");
            }
        }
        sw.Write("WHERE ");
        foreach (TableFieldInfo f in fields)
        {
            string fieldName = f.name;
            if (fieldName.ToUpper() == "DEFAULT")
                fieldName = "[" + fieldName + "]";

            if (f.readOnly == true)
                sw.Write(fieldName + "=@" + f.name);
        }
        sw.WriteLine(";\";");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\tList<SqlParameter> parms = new List<SqlParameter>();");
        sw.WriteLine("");
        foreach (TableFieldInfo f in fields)
        {
            if (getType(f.type) == "DateTime")
            {
                sw.WriteLine("\t\tif(_" + f.name + " != new DateTime(1753, 1, 1))");
                sw.WriteLine("\t\t\tparms.Add(new SqlParameter(\"@" + f.name + "\", _" + f.name + "));");
                sw.WriteLine("\t\telse");
                sw.WriteLine("\t\t\tparms.Add(new SqlParameter(\"@" + f.name + "\", null));");
            }
            else
            {
                sw.WriteLine("\t\tparms.Add(new SqlParameter(\"@" + f.name + "\", _" + f.name + "));");
            }
        }
        sw.WriteLine("");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\tif (_connectionString == \"\")");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t{");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t\tExecSQL(SQL, parms);");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t}");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\telse");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t{");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t\tExecSQL(_connectionString, SQL, parms);");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t}");
        sw.WriteLine("\t}");
        sw.WriteLine("");

        // Add the select method
        bool CanSelect = false;
        foreach (TableFieldInfo f in fields)
        {
            if (f.readOnly == true && CanSelect == false)
            {
                StatusBulletList.Items.Add(new ListItem("<--- public bool Select(" + getType(f.type) + " " + f.name + ")"));
                sw.WriteLine("\tpublic bool Select(" + getType(f.type) + " " + f.name + ")");
                CanSelect = true;
            }
        }
        if (CanSelect == true)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("\t{");
            foreach (TableFieldInfo f in fields)
            {
                if (f.readOnly == true)
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\tstring SQL = \"SELECT * FROM " + TableName + " WHERE " + f.name + "=@" + f.name + "\";");
            }
            sw.WriteLine("\t\tList<SqlParameter> parms = new List<SqlParameter>();");
            sw.WriteLine("");
            foreach (TableFieldInfo f in fields)
            {
                if (f.readOnly == true)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\tSqlParameter parm" + f.name + " = new SqlParameter(\"@" + f.name + "\", " + f.name + ");");
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\tparms.Add(parm" + f.name + ");");
                }
            }
            sw.WriteLine("");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\tDataTable table = null;");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\tif (_connectionString == \"\")");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\t{");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\t\ttable = ExecSQL(SQL, parms);");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\t}");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\telse");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\t{");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\t\ttable = ExecSQL(_connectionString, SQL, parms);");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\t}");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\tif (table != null && table.Rows.Count == 1)");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\t{");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\t\tDataRow row = table.Rows[0];");
            sw.WriteLine("");
            foreach (TableFieldInfo f in fields)
            {
                if (getType(f.type) == "string")
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\t\t_" + f.name + " = row[\"" + f.name + "\"].ToString();");
                else if (getType(f.type) == "int")
                {
                    //sw.WriteLine("\t\t\t_" + f.name + " = int.Parse(row[\"" + f.name + "\"].ToString());");
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\t\tif(!int.TryParse(row[\"" + f.name + "\"].ToString(), out _" + f.name + "))");
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t_" + f.name + " = -1;");
                }
                else if (getType(f.type) == "float")
                {
                    //sw.WriteLine("\t\t\t_" + f.name + " = int.Parse(row[\"" + f.name + "\"].ToString());");
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\t\tif(!float.TryParse(row[\"" + f.name + "\"].ToString(), out _" + f.name + "))");
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t_" + f.name + " = -1;");
                }
                else if (getType(f.type) == "bool")
                {
                    //sw.WriteLine("\t\t\t_" + f.name + " = int.Parse(row[\"" + f.name + "\"].ToString());");
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\t\tif(!bool.TryParse(row[\"" + f.name + "\"].ToString(), out _" + f.name + "))");
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t_" + f.name + " = false;");
                }
                else if (getType(f.type) == "DateTime")
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\t\tif(row[\"" + f.name + "\"].ToString() != \"\")");
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\t\t\tDateTime.TryParse(row[\"" + f.name + "\"].ToString(), out _" + f.name + ");");
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\t\telse");
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t_" + f.name + " = new DateTime(1753, 1, 1);");
                }
                else if (getType(f.type) == "byte[]")
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\t\tif (row[\"Img\"].ToString() != \"\")");
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t_" + f.name + " = (byte[])row[\"" + f.name + "\"];");
                }
                else
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\t\t//_" + f.name + " = row[\"" + f.name + "\"];");
            }
            sw.WriteLine("\t\t\treturn true;");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\t}");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\telse");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\t{");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\t\treturn false;");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\t}");
            sw.WriteLine("\t}");
            sw.WriteLine("");
        }

        // Add the SelectWhere method
        StatusBulletList.Items.Add(new ListItem("<--- public static DataTable SelectWhere(string WhereClause, List<SqlParameter> parms)"));
        sw.WriteLine("\tpublic static DataTable SelectWhere(string WhereClause, List<SqlParameter> parms)");
        sw.WriteLine("\t{");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\treturn SelectWhere(WhereClause, parms, \"\");");
        sw.WriteLine("\t}");
        sw.WriteLine("\tpublic static DataTable SelectWhere(string WhereClause, List<SqlParameter> parms, string connectionString)");
        sw.WriteLine("\t{");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\tstring SQL = \"SELECT * FROM " + TableName + " WHERE \" + WhereClause;");
        sw.WriteLine("");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\tDataTable table = null;");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\tif (connectionString == \"\")");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t{");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t\ttable = ExecSQL(SQL, parms);");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t}");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\telse");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t{");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t\ttable = ExecSQL(connectionString, SQL, parms);");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t}");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\treturn table;");
        sw.WriteLine("\t}");
        sw.WriteLine("");


        // Add the delete method
        if (CanSelect == true)
        {
            StatusBulletList.Items.Add(new ListItem("<--- public void Delete()"));
            sw.WriteLine("\tpublic void Delete()");
            sw.WriteLine("\t{");
            foreach (TableFieldInfo f in fields)
            {
                if (f.readOnly == true)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\tif(_" + f.name + " == -1)");
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\t\treturn;");
                    sw.WriteLine("");
                }
            }
            foreach (TableFieldInfo f in fields)
            {
                if (f.readOnly == true)
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\tstring SQL = \"DELETE FROM " + TableName + " WHERE " + f.name + "=@" + f.name + "\";");
            }
            sw.WriteLine("\t\tList<SqlParameter> parms = new List<SqlParameter>();");
            sw.WriteLine("");
            foreach (TableFieldInfo f in fields)
            {
                if (f.readOnly == true)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("\t\tparms.Add(new SqlParameter(\"@" + f.name + "\", " + f.name + "));");
                }
            }
            sw.WriteLine("");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\tif (_connectionString == \"\")");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\t{");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\t\tExecSQL(SQL, parms);");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\t}");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\telse");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\t{");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\t\tExecSQL(_connectionString, SQL, parms);");
            sw.WriteLine("\t\t}");
            sw.WriteLine("\t}");
            sw.WriteLine("");
        }

        // Add the Table method
        StatusBulletList.Items.Add(new ListItem("<--- public static DataTable Table()"));
        sw.WriteLine("\tpublic static DataTable Table()");
        sw.WriteLine("\t{");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\treturn Table(\"\");");
        sw.WriteLine("\t}");
        sw.WriteLine("\tpublic static DataTable Table(string connectionString)");
        sw.WriteLine("\t{");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\tstring SQL = \"SELECT * FROM " + TableName + ";\";");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\tList<SqlParameter> parms = new List<SqlParameter>();");
        sw.WriteLine("");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\tif (connectionString == \"\")");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t{");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t\treturn ExecSQL(SQL, parms);");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t}");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\telse");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t{");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t\treturn ExecSQL(connectionString, SQL, parms);");
        sw.WriteLine("\t\t}");
        sw.WriteLine("\t}");

        // Close the class
        sw.WriteLine("}");

        // Close the file
        sw.Close();
    }

    public static IDataReader ExecSQLReader(string DatabaseName, string SQL)
    {
        // Database access variables
        Database database = null;
        DbCommand command = null;
        IDataReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            if (DatabaseName != "")
                database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(DatabaseName);
            else
                database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
            command = database.GetSqlStringCommand(SQL);
            reader = database.ExecuteReader(command);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Remove stupid warning
            Exception x = e;
            e = x;
        }

        return reader;
    }

    private static string getType(string DBType)
    {
        string ret = DBType;

        if (DBType == "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString")
            ret = "string";
        else if (DBType == "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16")
            ret = "Int16";
        else if (DBType == "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32")
            ret = "int";
        else if (DBType == "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFloat")
            ret = "float";
        else if (DBType == "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDouble")
            ret = "float";
        else if (DBType == "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal")
            ret = "float";
        else if (DBType == "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBoolean")
            ret = "bool";
        else if (DBType == "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime")
            ret = "DateTime";
        else if (DBType == "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlByte")
            ret = "byte";
        else if (DBType == "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary")
            ret = "byte[]";

        return ret;
    }

    private class TableFieldInfo
    {
        public string name;
        public string type;
        public bool allowNull;
        public bool readOnly;
        public int maxSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to be using T4 for this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx is a reasonable place to start.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**1)** As already mentioned **T4** might be a better solution though I'm not sure whether it is available for earlier VS versions.

**2)** I would avoid using `string OutputPath` parameters, `Streams` are usually more handy.

**3)** Separate presentation and business logic code. Having `BulletedList` parameter in such a class seems to be completely wrong to me.

**4)** I think you should not even take this `BulletedList` (or anything similar) as parameter. This messages log is an **output** of your methods, not an **input**, so there is no point accepting it as parameter. Return it and remove method overloads which are not needed.

**5)**  **Naming convention** - usual rules are lower camel case for parameters.

**6)** Define variables closer to their first assignment and do not assign them any value if this value will be overwritten anyway. This is mostly about `CreateSingleTable` method. `ListDatabaseTables` also has 5 lines of code instead of maximum 3 needed.

**7)** I would make `ListDatabaseTables()` method more strongly typed. Returning a `DataTable` gives me absolutely no idea how to use it.

**8)** I prefer writing such constructions:

```
            if (f.readOnly)
                info += " (RO)";
            else
                info += " (RW)";
```

as:

```
info += f.readOnly ? " (RO)" : " (RW)";
```

This IMO shows more clearly that you're going to append *something* to `info` **anyway** and this *something* depends on `isReadonly` value.

**9)** I would replace this:

```
string info = "---> " + f.name + " (" + f.type + ")";
if (f.readOnly)
    info += " (RO)";
else
    info += " (RW)";
if (f.allowNull)
    info += " (Null)";
```

with this:

```
string info = string.Format("---> {0} ({1}) ({2}){3}"
                                 , f.name
                                 , f.type
                                 , f.readOnly? "RO" : "RW"
                                 , f.allowNull ? " (NULL)" : string.Empty);
```

This shows more clearly which format will `info` variable have. Also this has only one assignment which is better than doing `+=` on string several times.

**10)** `sw.WriteLine("// Inherit this class and make changes there");` I would prefer extending existing class instead of inheritance. Or at least you should **allow** extending it. In order to allow this generated classes are usually defined as `partial`.

**11)** A lot of repeats here:

```
        if (getType(f.type) == "int")
            sw.WriteLine("\tprivate " + getType(f.type) + " _" + f.name + " = -1;");
        else if (getType(f.type) == "float")
            sw.WriteLine("\tprivate " + getType(f.type) + " _" + f.name + " = -1;");
        else if (getType(f.type) == "DateTime")
            sw.WriteLine("\tprivate " + getType(f.type) + " _" + f.name + " = new DateTime(1753, 1, 1);");
        else if (getType(f.type) == "byte[]")
            sw.WriteLine("\tprivate " + getType(f.type) + " _" + f.name + " = new byte[1];");
        else
            sw.WriteLine("\tprivate " + getType(f.type) + " _" + f.name + ";");
```

It should be separated into at least two blocks:

**a)** write `private` + `type`
**b)** determine default value and write it (if any)

**12)** You have `new DateTime(1753, 1, 1);` repeated several times in your code. I would consider this string as magic string and I think it should be extracted into constant.

**13)** `fieldName.ToUpper() == "DEFAULT"`. `string.Equals(...)` has a parameter to ignore case.

**14)** You have just written your own `string.Join(...)` here:

```
    count = fields.Count;
    foreach (TableFieldInfo f in fields)
    {
        count--;
        if (f.readOnly != true)
        {
            if (count != 0)
                sw.Write("@" + f.name + ", ");
            else
                sw.Write("@" + f.name);
        }
    }
```

**15)** `if (f.readOnly == true && CanSelect == false)` I do not think this is the case when `bool` variable should be compared against `true` or `false`. I would prefer `if (f.readOnly && !CanSelect)`

**16)** Do not write god methods/classes and do not instantiate god objects. `CreateSingleTable` is definitely a god method - it has almost 500 lines of code !!! Raptors will come for you as soon as they will finish with `goto` writers. Break down this method into ~5-10 smaller methods.

**17)**

```
private static string getType(string DBType)
{
    string ret = DBType;

    if (DBType == "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString")
        ret = "string";
    else if (DBType == "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16")
        ret = "Int16";
    else if (DBType == "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32")
        ret = "int";
    else if (DBType == "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFloat")
        ret = "float";
    else if (DBType == "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDouble")
        ret = "float";
    else if (DBType == "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal")
        ret = "float";
    else if (DBType == "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBoolean")
        ret = "bool";
    else if (DBType == "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime")
        ret = "DateTime";
    else if (DBType == "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlByte")
        ret = "byte";
    else if (DBType == "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary")
        ret = "byte[]";

    return ret;
}
```

Instead of such constructions I usually use collections which contain mappings between input condition and desired result. I would replace your 10 conditions with this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dbTypeToDotNetTypeMappings =
    new Dictionary<string, string>();

dbTypeToDotNetTypeMappings.Add("System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString", "string");
// ... 
dbTypeToDotNetTypeMappings.Add("System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary", "byte[]");

string mappedType;
if (dbTypeToDotNetTypeMappings.TryGetValue(dbType, out mappedType))
    return mappedType;

return dbType;
```

This shows more clearly the fact that you have a lot of similar `input->output` transformations. Also it allows moving this conditions out of the code, to the configuration file for example.

**18)** `getType()` should be more strongly typed. It has to be `Type -> Type` mapping instead of `string -> string`.

**19)**

```
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Remove stupid warning
        Exception x = e;
        e = x;
    }
```

The best way to get rid of warning is logging the exception. Otherwise use `#pragma`:

```
#pragma warning disable 168
        catch (Exception e)
#pragma warning restore 168
        {

        }
```

Comment: For point 19, you could do `catch (Exception)` if you do not need the variable `e`.